# Can only get data from read_sql if the query is executed first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to read data into a DataFrame using `read_sql` and a SQLAlchemy query object. I'm getting zero rows returned, even though there's data in the database. Further, if I run the query with `query.all()`, then `read_sql` returns data.

For a concrete example

```
query = session.query(SomeSqlAlchemyModel)
# query.all()  # If I uncomment this line, I get data back. Without it I get an empty DataFrame.
df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, session.connection())
assert not df.empty
```

I'm logging out the SQL statements, and I've stepped into the SQLAlchemy code and from what I can tell, the exact same query is being executed in both scenarios.

How can I get `read_sql` to return data without running `query.all()` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem—I was inserting data into the database using the same session, and I hadn't called `flush` yet. The `query.all()` statement implicitly called a `flush` for me, persisting the data first.